# Any react-quill fix or update to work with React 17?

Tags: reactjs, react-quill

[React-Quill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill) (the latest version, i.e. 2.0.0-beta.2) currently does not work well with React 17. This package still uses React 16 and if version 17 is installed, a whole bunch of errors are thrown as described in [here](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill/issues/691).

I was wondering if anyone made a fix for this or knows when react-quill will be updated to work with React 17. From npm and github it seems that the package was last time updated a year ago and maintenance might have been abandoned all-together (which is regretful, a little under 200k weekly downloads on npmjs.com and going strong).

Alternatively, if you know (or almost know) how to manually update the package to work with React 17 please also post your ideas below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
npm i react-quill@2.0.0-beta.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with `react-quill` version2 and `react typescript` version17. I thought its about react-quill and react verions but the problem was about editor's style and i add this import to my code then it works perfectly.

`import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";`

[Demo (react-quill + react typescript)](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quill-with-react-typescript-fgs2vb)

[Demo (react-quill + react)](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quill-with-functional-component-68zcnt)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with react-quill while implementing it into my project, take a look at this
a detailed example of WYSIWYG editors **[here](https://ashint.hashnode.dev/)**